# Why am I not getting value of child value from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the value of uid from my Firebase database, which looks like that:

[image]

And below is my code to get its value

```
 mPostKey=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_id");
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles").child(mPostKey).child("uid");
    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mUid=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And my debugger is showing these values

[image]

I'm pointing to the uid correctly but I'm unable to get its value, I keep on getting null in mUid.

Comment: Debug your dataSnapshot object.

Comment: the function onDataChange is not running thats the problem, do you know what could be to reason?

Comment: onCancelled() is running ???

Comment: no, even it's not running

Comment: then try cleaning the project or invalid cashes and restart

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line of code:

```
mUid=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

with

```
String mUid=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

Add also this line of code after the above declaration to verify if it works:

```
Log.d("TAG", mUid);
```